# Are iterators of STL containers static variables?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

We can get iterators using the following statement:

```
vector::iterator it = v.begin();
```

Where is `vector::iterator` declared? (Can somebody give me  a link?)
What kind of thing is an iterator? I know the iterator concept, but is it a variable in class vector?

As per my understanding `vector::iterator` is a variable type of "it". So where this type is defined?

This may be a basic question, but I dont have a clear idea about this. Can somebody explain this?

Comment: It's defined in <vector> which you include and the files <vector> includes.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: You should consider reading a **book:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator is a class inside a class. In this case iterator is a class inside the class vector.
The iterator is defined inside the class to enable access to the class itself.

Iterators aren't static because that wouldn't allow iterating the container with two iterators (an operation that should be handled delicately).

Comment: Then vector::iterator is type of "it". am i correct?

Comment: I assume you mean that the type if the variable `it` is `vector::iterator`. In that case the answer is _yes_